# Python setuptools require a connection to the internet also for local packages

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, offline

I have a machine for which I don't have connection to the internet - the only connection is for the local organization network. As part of the execution process I want to install a local package by executing:

`pip install --no-deps --disable-pip-version-check --ignore-requires-python -e .`
(I included all switches that I thought can prevent pip to check packages online)

This pip install should be called during the stage when I don't have the connection to the internet.

I have built the package according to the new conventions that is described [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) with the toml file & setup.cfg file (without the setup.py file).

When I execute this command I receive the following:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Obtaining file:///home/roee/GIT/my_local_package
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=42 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=42
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

This is the toml file:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

This is the setup.cfg file:

```ini
[metadata]
name = my_mackage
version = 0.0.1
description = My package
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Operating System :: Linux

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    numpy
    matplotlib
    pathlib
    
[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

I work on ubuntu18.02.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Roee

Comment: Do you have setuptools installed?

Comment: yes. my setuptools version is 64.0.1

Comment: Maybe with [_`--no-index`_](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-index).

Comment: I have the same error message also with `--no-index`

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it with

```
pip install -e . --no-index --find-links="path/to/hatchling.whl"
```

which tells pip to not look online and take a local wheel.

I only tried it with `hatchling` but it probably works with `setuptools` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using this solution here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4557#issuecomment-569450071

> setuptools is already installed, as show in the output of pip list, so I shouldn't have to download it again.
>
> I noticed the use of pip of --ignore-installed and found on pip where that came from. PEP517 suggests that the package build should be done on an isolated environment which pip does by using --ignore-installed.

```bash
pip install --upgrade --no-index --no-build-insolation <MYPACKAGE>.tar.gz
```

Same command also works for `.whl`.

Comment: `no such option: --no-build-insolation`, need `--no-build-isolation`? :)